# Python sklearn: scoring

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring, grid-search

I want to use GridSearchCV by scoring label "1" for best f1-score, but somehow it optimizes for another metric, and I don't understand, here is my code;

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, f1_score
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label=1)
param_random = {'random_state': range(0,10)}
clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, max_features=1), param_random, scoring=f1_scorer)
```

Output,

```
Best parameters:  {'random_state': 8}
predict time: 0.0 s
accuracy: 0.840909090909
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.88      0.95      0.91        38
        1.0       0.33      0.17      0.22         6

avg / total       0.80      0.84      0.82        44
```

Second try, just changing 'random_sate',

```
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label=1)
param_random = {'random_state': range(0,100)}
clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, max_features=1), param_random, scoring=f1_scorer)
```

Output,

```
Best parameters:  {'random_state': 91}
predict time: 0.0 s
accuracy: 0.886363636364
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.88      1.00      0.94        38
        1.0       1.00      0.17      0.29         6

avg / total       0.90      0.89      0.85        44
```

Third try,

```
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label=1)
param_random = {'random_state': range(0,1000)}
clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, max_features=1), param_random, scoring=f1_scorer)
```

Output,

```
Best parameters:  {'random_state': 273}
predict time: 0.001 s
accuracy: 0.840909090909
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.90      0.92      0.91        38
        1.0       0.40      0.33      0.36         6

avg / total       0.83      0.84      0.83        44
```

So, at first, I thought it optimizes according to label '0', it doesn't. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Although it looks it's fine, I know that there is at least one better score in this range.

How do I know something wrong, because I was able to find better one manually,

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, f1_score
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label=1)
param_random = {'random_state': range(2,3)}
clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, max_features=1), param_random, scoring=f1_scorer)

Best parameters:  {'random_state': 2}
predict time: 0.0 s
accuracy: 0.886363636364
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.90      0.97      0.94        38
        1.0       0.67      0.33      0.44         6

avg / total       0.87      0.89      0.87        44
```

Comment: `random_state` is the seed used by the random number generator. I don't think it's a good idea to tune it by using grid search. You could tune `n_estimators` and `max_features` instead

Comment: Since `f1_score` is a predefined metric and `pos_label=1` is the default value, I think you can discard `make_scorer` and use `scoring='f1'` directly

Comment: @tuliocasagrande, First, I did with other parameters as you said, but still, I couldn't optimize as how I want (f1, label 1). And I tried `scoring='f1'`, too. It didn't change anything. I know `random_state` is not a good choice to tune, I will definitely remove it once I find how to optimize as I want. Thanks

Comment: You are also using n_estimators as 1 which is a wrong choice for RFC. RFC does good only when there are a valid number of trees (so that it works as an ensemble classifier). If you are setting it to 1 its just like its growing the tree randomly always and throwing out the results.

Comment: @hashcode55, yes, I'm also aware that, too. It is against the RFC logic, I'll probably change that when I find a solution for my problem. For now, I'll keep it since it provides the best score, although I am not sure why.